# Antibody test after vaccination with BBIBP-CorV

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, antibodies

After vaccination with BBIBP-CorV (inactivated) which of the following tests can be taken to determine if the vaccine produced an immune response:

1. IgM for N protein
2. IgG for N protein
3. IgG for S protein

Sorry if it's obvious, but I'm not an expert and cannot find a clear answer after googling for an hour.
My current understanding that it's test 2 - IgG for N protein for inactivated vaccines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR;
3 - IgG for S protein

From [Safety and immunogenicity of an inactivated SARS-CoV-2 vaccine, BBIBP-CorV: a randomised, double-blind, placebo-controlled, phase 1/2 trial](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7561304/):

> The secondary outcome was immunogenicity, assessed as the neutralising
> antibody responses against infectious SARS-CoV-2.

From [What are COVID-19 neutralising antibody rapid tests and why use them?](https://www.abingdonhealth.com/what-are-covid-19-neutralising-antibody-rapid-tests/)

> Neutralising antibodies bind to the SARS-CoV-2 Spike protein and
> interfere with the virus’ ability to enter human cells. IgG antibodies
> are the most common antibody in blood and have the largest part to
> play in conferring immunity to bacteria or viruses.